# The code viewer isn't good

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign

In your opinion, Which code viewer is better?

this is the code viewer of the Stack:

[image: figure 1]

and this is another code viewer:

[image: figure2]

Really Why doesn't the Stack has a good code viewer?

Comment: Related: http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/340/syntax-highlighting-should-be-supported-on-electrical-engineering-like-on-so

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two problems. The first is that you're confusing StackExchange with an IDE.

The code highlighting doesn't work on [your question here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/121346/spi1-doesnt-work) because you have put a whole lot of relatively worthless tags on your question instead of one that defines the language you are using. For example, if you used [c](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c) instead of each individual microcontroller you used, you wouldn't have an issue. I have changed your tags and now syntax highlighting shows up.

Comment: WoW! Thanks, the stack is really clever!

Comment: Ultimately the purpose of tags is primarily to organize topics by relevance, so one should really use the language hinting code rather than a tag if highlighting is the only goal.

Comment: @Roh  A better way to enable appropriate syntax highlighting (code coloring) is to prefix the code block with `<!-- language: lang-c -->`.  Here's an [example](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/59419/msp430-printf-through-spy-bi-wire-hangs) (you should look at the text in edit mode).  Full list of syntax highlighting options [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79785/syntax-highlighting-what-about-answering-with-a-different-language-than-the-one).